# Deep array key paths

Tags: php

Having this kind of groups structure

```
Public [id=1]
|—Registered [id=2]
|—|—Author [id=3]
|—|—|—Editor [id=4]
|—|—|—|—Publisher [id=5]
|—Manager [id=6]
|—|—Administrator [id=7]
```

Having this initial descriptive array:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 0
        [group] => Public
        [parent] => 0
    )

    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 2
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 1
        [group] => Registered
        [parent] => Public
    )

    [3] => Array (
        [id] => 3
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 2
        [group] => Author
        [parent] => Registered
    )

    [4] => Array (
        [id] => 4
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 3
        [group] => Editor
        [parent] => Author
    )

    [5] => Array (
        [id] => 5
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 4
        [group] => Publisher
        [parent] => Editor
    )

    [6] => Array (
        [id] => 6
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 1
        [group] => Manager
        [parent] => Public
    )

    [7] => Array (
        [id] => 7
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 6
        [group] => Administrator
        [parent] => Manager
    )
)
```

Need to process this array and add [inh] key that will hold value of bottom-top path of keys:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 0
        [group] => Public
        [parent] => 0
        [inh] => Array(0)
    )

    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 2
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 1
        [group] => Registered
        [parent] => Public
        [inh] => Array(1,0)
    )

    [3] => Array (
        [id] => 3
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 2
        [group] => Author
        [parent] => Registered
        [inh] => Array(2,1,0)
    )

    [4] => Array (
        [id] => 4
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 3
        [group] => Editor
        [parent] => Author
        [inh] => Array(3,2,1,0)
    )

    [5] => Array (
        [id] => 5
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 4
        [group] => Publisher
        [parent] => Editor
        [inh] => Array(4,3,2,1,0)
    )

    [6] => Array (
        [id] => 6
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 1
        [group] => Manager
        [parent] => Public
        [inh] => Array(1,0)
    )

    [7] => Array (
        [id] => 7
        [descript] => 
        [parent_id] => 6
        [group] => Administrator
        [parent] => Manager
        [inh] => Array(6,1,0)
    )
)
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this without using recursivity or classes?
In the worst case I agree to use recursive functions.
Tried to write a recursive func but no success so far.

Comment: Without looping entirely you mean?

Comment: I guess I cannot avoid not to use loops...

Comment: Array walk, iterator apply and array walk recursive come to mind.

Comment: I meant using foreach is ok

Answer (score 1):

Assuming array key equal `id`

```
function parentList($map, &$element){
    if(!isset($element['inh'])){
        if($pid = $element['parent']){
            $element['inh'] = array_merge([$pid], parentList($map, $map[$pid]));
        }else{
            $element['inh'] = [];
        }
    }
    return $element['inh'];
}

foreach($a as &$e){
    parentList($a, $e);
}
```

https://ideone.com/0oYygq

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I will another function.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this works

```
function setAllGroupsInheritanceSQL (&$allGroups, $parent=0) {
    foreach ($allGroups as $k=>$grp_arr) {
        if ($grp_arr['parent_id']==$parent) {
            $child=$grp_arr['id'];
            if (isset($allGroups[$parent]['inh'])) $inherit_arr=$allGroups[$parent]['inh'];
            $inherit_arr[]=$parent;
            $allGroups[$child]['inh']=$inherit_arr;
            setAllGroupsInheritanceSQL ($allGroups, $child);
        }
    }
}
```